# Left Join with scalaquery on sqlite

Tags: sqlite, scala, left-join, scalaquery

I'm using scalaquery on a sqlite database (with the [zentus jdbc driver](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/)), but when I select with a left join, I got the following Exception :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: unrecognized token: "{"
    at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:114)
    at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.<init>(PrepStmt.java:37)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:231)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:224)
    at org.scalaquery.session.Session$class.prepareStatement(Session.scala:25)
    at org.scalaquery.session.BaseSession.prepareStatement(Session.scala:92)
    at org.scalaquery.StatementInvoker.results(StatementInvoker.scala:59)
    ...
```

My query is :

```
val qSong = for{
  Join(song,score) <- Songs leftJoin Scores on (_.hash is _.hash)
  __ <- Query orderBy song.title
} yield song.title ~ song.difficulty ~ song.level ~ song.mode ~ score.perfect ~ score.great
```

And when I print the generated query, it give me this :

```
SELECT "t2"."title","t2"."difficulty","t2"."level","t2"."mode","t3"."perfect","t3"."great" FROM {oj "song" "t2" left outer join "score" "t3" on ("t2"."hash"="t3"."hash")} ORDER BY "t2"."title"
```

It's seems it comes from the `{oj` part that's the driver doesn't handle.
So is there a way to make a left join without the `oj` keyword ? Or is there another driver which handle it ?

Thanks.

Comment: you can also try asking at http://groups.google.com/group/scalaquery